# Replace numbers "4,16221E+13"

Tags: python, excel, numbers

I have a cvs file containing the following format of numbers **4,16221E+13** I don't really know what it means.

How can I replace them? is there a special function or script to do it?

Thank you,
Hani.

Comment: I think you should confirm with you data provider because when I enter  4,16221E+13 in excel cell, it was converted to 4162210000000000000, which is 4.16221E*10^18

Comment: I tried in office 2007

Comment: 4,16221E+13 could represent different numbers in different countries

Comment: @glasslion: Actually it looks like there's a bug in Python with this. When I set my locale to one where the decimal point is a comma, like `'french_france'`, the expression `float('4,16221E+13')` still results in a `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4,16221E+13`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means `4.16221 x 10^13`, i.e. `41622100000000`.

You can use:

```
float('4,16221E+13'.replace(',', '.'))
>>> 41622100000000.0
```

Python needs `.` as decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the text, replace the `,` with an `.` then you can get the number it's likely supposed to be, eg:

```
>>> f = '4,16221E+13'
>>> float(f.replace(',', '.'))
41622100000000.0
```